# How call script Python from an "executable" jar?

Tags: java, python-2.7, interpreter

I am trying to make a Java application that by clicking a button should call a script python. In the method of the button I have set the PythonInterpreter and a couple of variables I need to pass as arguments to the script:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);
        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

        // Insert arguments as input for the script
        interp.set("path", path);
        interp.set("logcatName", dev1+"_Video"+i+".txt");
        interp.set("logcatSecondDevice", dev2+"_Video"+i+".txt");
        interp.set("descriptionPath", descriptionPath);

        interp.execfile("C:\\adp\\cutVideo.py");
```

The following instead are instruction to call the function in the script by passing the arguments above:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  cut_video(path, logcatName, logcatSecondDevice, descriptionPath)
```

Everything works perfectly if I run this by using NetBeans but if I try to run by the jar file I should make, it does not work anymore.
Is there another way to make it working?

Comment: I could be wrong here as I'm not a programmer but as jar's run in a JVM which is, in essence a virtual machine, would this possibly be because there isn't a python instance inside the JVM? Possibly if you made an external call to python it might work. Again, apologies if this is nonsense.

Comment: @KeefBaker starting a response with "I'm not a programmer" is not a great place to start :P I think he's trying to use the Jython library, which is python embedded in Java. Carlito, can you print t he error message from the Jar file so we have a better idea of where to start?

Comment: @nameless912 I put the error message below as answer. As I said there, I could even call the script by putting it in another folder (i.g. I put it on C:\adp\script.py) but unfortunately it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by putting the script on another folder and calling it with the instruction:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "python", "C:\\adp\\cutVideo.py", path, descriptionPath);
Process move = pb.start();
```